# Java URL creating from few strings

Tags: java, url

I want to create URL using : existing url and 2 strings

I found

```
Create URL from a String
```

and

```
File.separator or File.pathSeparator
```

but I want to create it without typing '/'

> String part1 = "txt1";
>
> String part2 = "txt2";
>
> URL urlBase = new URL(some adress);

now I can write

> URL urlNew = urlBase.toURI().resolve(part1).toURL();

but how to add part2 goal is to get adress/txt1/txt2

Comment: Your question is difficult to read. Is what you want: `URL urlNew = urlBase.toURI().resolve(part1 + "/" + part2).toURL();`?

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply, solution is correct but I want to achieve same result without usage of '/'. Do you know how to do that ?

Comment: `URL urlNew = urlBase.toURI().resolve(part1 + (char)47 + part2).toURL();`

Comment: That was a joke comment btw. `http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URI.html#relativize(java.net.URI)` might be useful. But I don't know this API very well.

Comment: does `URL urlNew = urlBase.toURI().resolve(part1).resolve(part2).toURL();` work?

Comment: No, only part1 has been replaced with part2.

Answer (score 0):

Will this help?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {
        URL domain = new URL("http://google.com");
        URL url = new URL(domain, "test");
        System.out.println(url.toString());
    }
```

Or

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {
        URL domain = new URL("http://google.com/sample/text/a");
        URL url = new URL(domain, "test");
        System.out.println(url.toString());
    }
```

Notice that it will add the string to your domain.

Comment: Thanks for reply, result : http://google.com/sample/text/test, but I want to get http://google.com/sample/text/a/test. 'Cruncher' solution is correct but it involves usage of '/' that like I wrote I'm trying to avoid (assumption: we can do this without typing '/')

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    URL urlBase = new URL("http://google.com/2");
    String part1 = "test1/3";
    String part2 = "test2";
    System.out.println(
            urlBase.toString()
            + new URL(urlBase, part1).getPath()
            + new URL(urlBase, part2).getPath()
        );
}
```

No character is required :)

If you have an empty string, it won't work, so this is the solution for it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        URL urlBase = new URL("http://google.com/2");
        String part1 = "test1/3";
        String part2 = "test2";
        System.out.println(
                urlBase.toString()
                + (part1.isEmpty() ? "" : new URL(urlBase, part1).getPath())
                + (part2.isEmpty() ? "" : new URL(urlBase, part2).getPath())
            );
    }
```